# Best matching OEM drivers for my device?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to test my android app on my android device, which is a Samsung Galaxy Trend Lite (also called Samsung Galaxy Fresh) GT-S7390. However, Samsung doesn't provide the OEM drivers for that device! Hence, so far, Eclipse doesn't recognize my device when I plug it in my computer.

Could I maybe install drivers of another, related device? Would it work? If yes, which device would be the closest to mine in that respect? (Here are some info on it : http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_fresh_s7390-5841.php)

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

You just can try to install Samsung Kies. There're all necessary drivers implemented.

Otherwise you could try to install the Samsung USB Driver from the developer sction:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows